# How do you split string elements of csv file correctly to achieve the following list?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I want python to read a csv file that contains rows of integers. I want to take the elements from each row of a CSV file and put them into a list, then use all the lists as values for keys in a dictionary:

The expected output:

```
{'2020-12-20': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '206'], '2020-12-27': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1,799'], '2021-01-03': ['0','0', '0', '0', '3,787']}
```

To do that, I need to split each row at the commas. However, some of these integers are actually strings like `"1,799"`. so by splitting each row at the commas, I'd be breaking `"1,799"` into `"1` and `799"`

if I have a csv with data like this `2020-12-27,0,0,0,0,"1,799",` in each row, how do I split the data such that I get `'1,799'` instead of `"1` and `799"`??

How do I use the csv module to do so??

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to use the `csv` module to read the CSV file.

Comment: csv module definitely supports quoting to protect separator

Comment: how do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module:

If `data.csv` contains:

```
2020-12-27,0,0,0,0,"1,799"
2020-12-28,1,2,3,4,"2,800"
```

then:

```
import csv

all_data = {}
with open("data.csv", "r") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    for line in reader:
        all_data[line[0]] = line[1:]

print(all_data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "2020-12-27": ["0", "0", "0", "0", "1,799"],
    "2020-12-28": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "2,800"],
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! how do I remove the dates (ie: "2020-12-27") from the list? The list is supposed to include only the numbers, without the dates.
the dates are supposed to be the keys for the dictionary, while the lists are supposed to be the values

Comment: @eshtabel3asal Change the line where you append the data to `all_data` to `all_data.append(line[1:])`

Comment: but how do I set this up to be a dictionary whose values are lists? instead of a list of lists..? I'm trying to do this `key = line.split(',')[0]` but it keeps giving me errors bc I cant do split with lists

Comment: sure, I just clarified it to make it a bit clearer. the expected outcome is the dictionary and you need to scroll to the side to see the end of it.

Comment: thank you! can you please explain where the list (which is used as a value for the dictionary) was created? I don't really understand what you did and I’d like to learn how it’s done :)

Comment: @eshtabel3asal Take look at documenation of [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) The final dictionary is created from first column value as key and the rest as a value.